# Can I use a 12V and a 5V line from a PC power supply to get a safely useable 7V

Tags: power-supply

I'd like to connect a fan at 7V in a PC.  If I connect the fan's + to a 12V rail and - to a 5V rail, can I safely use that for 7V?  Would the current rating just be the lower of what the 5V and 12V rail will handle?

Comment: Why not run the fan from +5, or replace it with a 24V fan and run it from +12?  Either would do almost the same thing.

Comment: Now that it's pointed out to me, this does indeed seem like a duplicate of that question. I do think however the answer from Transistor is more comprehensive than the ones on that questions. Can we merge them somehow?

Comment: -1 for not providing specs in a vague question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is probably not.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fOXpj4.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. A simplified representation of a switched-mode power supply output.*

The problem isn't your maths - it's the current flow. Both the 12 V and 5 V supplies are designed to *source* current. It can only flow *out* through the diodes. In your configuration you are asking the 5 V supply to *sink* current. In most cases - and almost certainly in yours - the 5 V supply can not do this. There is no way for it to bleed off current to pull the voltage down. D2 stops reverse current flow.

> What is the situation if the 5 V supply is already sourcing more current than the fan draws? Will it simply impose noise on the 5 V rail? – Andrew Morton

In this case it would work. The load would draw off the current. e.g., Fan requires 100 mA, 5 V load requires 150 mA then the fan supplies 100 mA and the 5 V supply another 50 mA.

**But** what happens if the 5 V load is reduced to 80 mA? The voltage will rise on the 5 V line and most logic chips will be destroyed at 6 to 6.5 V. (CMOS is an obvious exception as it can go to 15 V.)

Comment: What is the situation if the 5 V supply is already sourcing more current than the fan draws? Will it simply impose noise on the 5 V rail?

Comment: Good point, although OP didn't mention that. See the update.

Comment: THe fan basically supplements current to the 5V load, where the load is assumed to be greater.

Comment: Is it possible merge this answer to the earlier duplicate question?

Answer (score 3):

This was asked like a week ago.. [Undervolting PC Fan from 12V to 7V](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/259378/undervolting-pc-fan-from-12v-to-7v/259384#259384).

Short answer, technically yes it could work. As long as 5v rail is constantly sourcing more power than the fans maximum pull. I don't really recommend it though.

Answer (score 2):

LDO's are emitter followers with no active pulldown so with no load it will fail and 5V will rise.

However if there is a static load externally on the 5V rail, that pulls down the +5V  voltage opposed by a regulator that pumps up the current (and V ), then a light fan current only decreases the main 5V load very slightly and will work properly.

Fans only take <5W and this is 1~2% of typical CPU power supplies with the assumption that is what you are using.  If not then a dummy load on 5V to offset opposing fan current is needed.