# How exactly does getting 7V by connecting both terminals to the 12V and 5V sources work?

Tags: power-supply, voltage, dc, fan, pc

When I Googled MOLEX pinouts and checked [some questions on Stack Exchange](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/259378/undervolting-pc-fan-from-12v-to-7v/259384#259384). I saw interesting images where if you were to connect both the 5V and 12V ends of the PSU connector to a device, you would get 7V power.

How does this work? Doesn't DC work by forming a loop from positive to the negative? I don't know much about the electronics other than reading MAKE books back in the day so I am curious.

Comment: It only works if the 5 V supply can sink current as well as supply it. That can also happen if there is enough load already attached to the 5 V supply. But it can also go very wrong, if not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes 12V - 5V= 7V.

The catch is 12V would source current but the 5V is being pulled up and you would need a 5V load on the MOBO to prevent overvoltage shutdown from any load sinking current more than what might being sourced up to 12V difference load to use that 7V.

The Forward converters pulse charge up to 5V via tightly coupled transformers and rely on load to bring down. (AFAIK)

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fviSet.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

By the way, the same is true for Buck converters and LDO's, whereas a "push-pull regulator" can source or sink current.